# Ionic 3/Angular 4 simple form validation - jit_nodeValue15(...) is not a function

Tags: forms, angular, ionic3

I have a super simple form, where i want to check if the user filled out the datefrom.

Here's my form:

```
<ion-content padding>
<form #signoff="ngForm" novalidate>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="col-left">
        <label class="select_label">{{datefrom_data.title}}</label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="col-right">
        <input class="select_control" name="signoff.datefrom_name" type="date" [(ngModel)]="datefrom" (click)="showDatePicker()" required>    
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-col>  
</ion-row>
<ion-row class="Bemerkung">
  <ion-col>   
    <ion-label>Bemerkung:</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea class="signoff-textarea" name="signoff.comment_name" [(ngModel)]="addtionalInfo">
      </ion-textarea>
  </ion-col>  
</ion-row>
<button ion-button class="maincolor" block [disabled]="!signoff.form.valid" (click)="signoff()">Kind abmelden</button>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

in my signoff.ts i have the signoff() function.
The validation on the button works but as soon as I click the button I receive a runtime error: "jit_nodeValue15(...) is not a function"

[image]

If I remove the form the button click event works again.

My enviroment:

Ionic Framework: 3.0.1
Angular Core: 4.0.0
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.0

signoff.ts:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5680ad02f00d9fe40466e0b2d2409834

EDIT:
- added signoff.ts
- added error image

Comment: post your typescript file please

Comment: i've added a link

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the function from signoff() to signoffChild() and now it works...